# spliting one array into 3 different arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have an php array. I want to split this array into 2 arrays. please see below example:-

```
$arrayIhave = array (
  'id' => '1',
  'name' => 'ripa',
  'roll' => '10',
  'country' => 'india',
  'state' => 'WB',
  'status' => 'active'
);
```

I need to split this one into the following:-

```
$array1 = array(
  'id' => '1',
  'status' => 'active'
);

$array2 = array(
  'name' => 'ripa',
  'roll' => '10'
);

$array3 = array(
  'country' => 'india',
  'state' => 'WB'
);
```

So, what will be the best and professional solution?

Comment: Firstly, obvious point, but your output shows 3 arrays, not 2. Secondly [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) We are not here to write your code for you.

Comment: do you just want to spit the array every 2 rows?

Comment: yes my exaple is showing 3 arrays not 2. But my basic question is "Is there any function in php which will split an containing key range." suppose key 5-10 will make an individual array.

Answer (score 2):

Am not sure how you got the array messed up but You can simply use `array_chunk` to split them into 2 parts

```
 list($array1,$array2,$array3) = array_chunk($arrayIhave, 2,true);
```

Or Just use template to define position of your elements

```
$template = array(
        array("id"=>null,"name"=>null),
        array("name"=>null,"roll"=>null),
        array("country"=>null,"state"=>null)
        );


$arrayIhave = array (
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'ripa',
        'roll' => '10',
        'country' => 'india',
        'state' => 'WB',
        'status' => 'active'
);

foreach ( $template as $var ) {
    $var = array_intersect_key($arrayIhave, $var);
    var_dump($var);
}
```

Output

```
array (size=2)
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'name' => string 'ripa' (length=4)
array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'ripa' (length=4)
  'roll' => string '10' (length=2)
array (size=2)
  'country' => string 'india' (length=5)
  'state' => string 'WB' (length=2)
```

Comment: Sorry , It will not fulfill my purpose.

Comment: See updated code using template

Comment: No , not this lengthy process....

Comment: Only one loop is not a lengthy  process .. the template is just to define the grouping .. and you don't need to repeat it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the functions `array_intersect_key` and `array_flip` (the latter function flips keys and values in an aray):

```
$array1 = array_intersect_key($arrayIhave, array_flip(array('id', 'status')));
$array2 = array_intersect_key($arrayIhave, array_flip(array('name', 'roll')));
$array3 = array_intersect_key($arrayIhave, array_flip(array('country', 'state')));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the new arrays based on data from the original array, using the associative keys to access the elements:

```
$array1 = array(
  'id' => $arrayIhave['id'],
  'status' => $arrayIhave['active']
);

$array2 = array(
  'name' => $arrayIhave['name'],
  'roll' => $arrayIhave['roll']
);

$array3 = array(
  'country' => $arrayIhave['country'],
  'state' => $arrayIhave['state']
);
```

Comment: Sorry , It is not the best way :(

Comment: @RipaSaha It's definitely the fastest, so perhaps you'd want to be more detailed in your reply.

Comment: @RipaSaha looks like you have some requirements that you haven't posted, which you are evaluating the answers based on.

Comment: @MrCode If the parent array contains 150 elements then what will you say?

Comment: @RipaSaha that is exactly what you should have posted in the question. I've voted to close because the question is vague and based on that comment, you have not disclosed all of the information required to produce a suitable answer.

Comment: @MrCode Whatever You have voted I don't care about that. But If you want to know the answer you need to wait. I will provide the answer here. and obviously one thing keep in mind, when you answering anything , give solution thinking in broad sense. Best of Luck. :)

Comment: @MrCode extremely very sorry for behaving like this.please don't mind.Actually I was middle of a project and stuck on that problem.so got angry.I found the solution of my above issue.I want to give answer of that issue.please vote for me so that I can put my answer.